# "Rush-hour" OR "Rush-hours"?

Tags: meaning

Many people call it **"Rush-hour"** when there is a lot of traffic on roads in the morning or evening. Should not it be called **"Rush-hours"** because the huge traffic continues for many hours during that time??

Comment: Rush hour: 
*A regular period of heavy traffic, especially at the beginning or end of a workday.* It is an idiomatic expression that refers to a specific period that may last less but generally more than an hour. Rush hours suggest a number of these periods: I.e. ...during morning  rush hours, that is the rush hour that you have every morning.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rush-hour

Comment: Unfortunately, the correct use of these types of expressions must be memorized.  While "happy-hour" is usually two to three hours in duration, "cocktail-hour" refers to a single hour. Both are time periods set aside for imbibing, but only "cocktail-hour" might be pluralized:  "The caterer provides  hot hors d'oeuvres during cocktail-hours,"  BUT,  "The bar has free snacks during happy-hour."

Answer (score 2):

It's an expression that doesn't need a plural. Kind of the same way you don't call two banknotes or two coins "moneys". You should of course not use rush-hour to determine an exact point in time, such as "we'll meet after the rush-hour".